# How can I call the web service with Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xml, web-services, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin APP where I want to call the Web Service
I don't get any Result from the Web Service but the following Exception:

> "An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. Check InnerException for exception details."

I've seen a lot of YouTube Vedio and surfed the Internet for a long time, but I haven't found a solution.

This is my Web Service:

```
//web Service from ASMX project
public class WStest : System.Web.Services.WebService { 

    [WebMethod(MessageName = "Test", Description = "test")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(Result))]
    public Result test() {
        Result result = new Result();

        result.msg = "test successful";
        result.flag = 1;
        result.userNum = "usernummer";

        return result;
    }
}
```

this is just a part of Xammrain Code

```
private void Butsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    WStest.WStest test = new WStest.WStest();

    test.testCompleted += Test_testCompleted;

    test.testAsync();   //call Web Service
   

    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}

 private void Test_testCompleted(object sender, WStest.testCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var a = e.Result.msg;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //here I get the exception
            }
  
        }
```

and thanks for all Answers

Comment: You are throwing yourself `       throw new NotImplementedException();` a the end of Butsend_Click or was it a typo?.

Comment: why is my code doing exactly what I tell it to do?  `throw new NotImplementedException();`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing a bid again NotImplementedException (); at the end of the method, you can only comment :)

Comment: Hi @Gabriel Ribeiro Rossi  thanks for the quick answer and
sorry for my bad english
I am developing a Xamarin APP for the first time
I want to call the web service
I don't get any result from the web service but the following Exciption

   "An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. Check InnerException for exception details."

I've seen a lot of YouTube Vedio and surfed the Internet for a long time, but I haven't found a solution.


thanks for support

Comment: this my function 
        private void Test_testCompleted(object sender, WStest.testCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var a = e.Result.msg;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
  
        }